# How to check if one DateTime is later than another in javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, datetime

Through the form i am getting two values like

```
   Start datetime = '01/12/2013 12:00:00 AM' and
   End datetime = '02/12/2013 12:00:00 AM'.
```

How I can validate the start datetime must be less than end datetime in javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Asuming you received a date in Javascript Date format you need `Date.parse()` function or compare by comparison operators. It will return the milliseconds that have passed since 01/01/1970 00:00

Somehow like this:

```
if(Date.parse(datetimeStart) < Date.parse(datetimeEnd)){
   //start is less than End
}else{
   //end is less than start
}
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3yXCY/3/)

Comment: This assumes that the Date.parse can correctly handle the string it is given. For non US dates or non-ISO dates or user supplied dates, Date.parse can fail to recognise the date delimiters or the date format, so confuse 2/3/21 as 3rd of February (US format) or 2nd Feb (UK format). Either validate and convert to a known format (ie: convert to US/ISO) or use a library like moment.js to handle formatting/conversion.

Answer (score 15):

its really simple in javascript

```
var startTime = new Date('01/12/2013 12:00:00 AM');
var endTime = new Date('02/12/2013 12:00:00 AM');
```

and then all you need to do is compare

```
if( startTime < endTime){
   alert("start time is lesser");
}
```

More on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-dates-with-javascript)

Comment: This assumes that the Date() can correctly handle the string it is given. For non US dates or non-ISO dates or user supplied dates, Date() can fail to recognise the date delimiters or the date format, so confuse 2/3/21 as 3rd of February (US format) or 2nd Feb (UK format). Either validate and convert to a known format (ie: convert to US/ISO) or use a library like moment.js to handle formatting/conversion.

Comment: not working ------

Fri Aug 18 2023 11:09:09 GMT+0300>Tue Aug 22 2023 07:42:50 GMT+0300 true

how can be 18.08.2023 11.09 higger then 22.08.2023 7:42

 console.log(new Date(updated_at)+'>'+new Date(date), new Date(date) > new Date(updated_at));

Answer (score 2):

```
//StartDate & EndDate two dates

if (StartDate < EndDate)
   // code

if you just want the dates, and not the time

if (StartDate.Date < EndDate.Date)
    // code
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare only dates then this will work.

```
var dt1 = new Date('12/31/2013');
var dt2 = new Date('12/31/2014');
var dt1obj = Date.parse(dt1);
var dt2obj = Date.parse(dt2);
if(dt2obj <= dt1obj){
//your code here...
}else{
//your code here...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this following code:**

```
function dateCheck() {
    var fDate = new Date("26/05/2013");
    var lDate = new Date("24/05/2013");
    if(fDate <= lDate) {
        alert("true");
        return true;
    }
    alert("false");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var record_day1=fromDate.split("/");
    var sum1=record_day1[1]+'/'+record_day1[0]+'/'+record_day1[2];  
    var record_day2=toDate.split("/");
    var sum2=record_day2[1]+'/'+record_day2[0]+'/'+record_day2[2];  
    var record1 = new Date(sum1);
    var record2 = new Date(sum2); 
    if(record2 < record1)
    {
            alert("End date must be greater than start date");
            return false;
    }
```

Here we are splitting the date and then combining it for comparing it hope it will work thanks.....:)

Answer (score 0):

use the date object

```
    Date1 = new Date('01/12/2013 12:00:00 AM');
    Date2 = new Date('02/12/2013 12:00:00 AM');
    Date1-Date2//in millisecond
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Date.parse` as following

```
if (Date.parse(datetimeStart) < Date.parse(datetimeEnd)) {} else {}
```

Comment: This assumes that the Date.parse can correctly handle the string it is given. For non US dates or non-ISO dates or user supplied dates, Date.parse can fail to recognise the date delimiters or the date format, so confuse 2/3/21 as 3rd of February (US format) or 2nd Feb (UK format). Either validate and convert to a known format (ie: convert to US/ISO) or use a library like moment.js to handle formatting/conversion.