# Forward webpage for specific time

Tags: html, local, offline

Is it possible to forward a webpage at a specific moment (date - time) for a specific time, say 1 hour?

It is for an offline webpage students use as supplement on a Art-test, with pictures and movies. It must be available for only 1 hour.

It's just local html or php with some javascript.

Comment: Please be more elaborate with "forward a webpage", do you mean forward a form after set period of time, or all the elements, or elements and data? However, I can tell you right away, it will never be tinker proof. Someone who will have adequate knowledge of Javascript can edit the time if they so wish.

Comment: Normally the site says something like: "This page is currently unavailable" , but at time of the test it must be forward to a page with images. It is no big deal if some kids have fun to hack this site, let them. A. It is offline, just on schools intranet and B. they are just a supplement with pictures and parts of movies. Not the test itselves.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but this question needs more details to be answered helpfully. How are users going to access the HTML file(s)? Are you running a server (PHP doesn't run in the browser)? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that would not be too hard. The quickest way would have 2 pages, say `index` and `stuff`.

You would need to check if the current datetime is [within datetimes/after the set datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20322507/how-to-check-if-one-datetime-is-later-than-another-in-javascript).

If it is then [redirecting them to the `stuff` page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/506004/2941909), to show all the materials.

If not, just output text with `document.write();`.