# I have tried to disabled past dates , now i want my "date_to" field dates greater than "date_from" field date

Tags: javascript

I want my departure date not greater than arrival date, like if i have selected 4 Aug on arrival, disable departure date less than that.

```js
$(function(){
              
      //arrival date 
     date_from.min = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];
      //departure date 
     date_to.min   = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];    

  })
```

```html
<input type="date"  class="tour-search-input" name="arrival" id="date_from" placeholder="DD/MM/YY">


<input type="date" class="tour-search-input" name="departure" id="date_to" placeholder="DD/MM/YY">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: as your title where is your tried code?

Comment: Already answered by many here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20322507/how-to-check-if-one-datetime-is-later-than-another-in-javascript