# React Recharts - How to add filters for line graph?

Tags: reactjs, filter, graph, next.js, recharts

In nextjs application, I am trying to add `recharts` https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/SimpleLineChart. Now I want to add filter option for the charts like 1 day, 1 week, 1 month, etc. How can I customise the graph? Or can I use different plugin which supports my requirement? please suggest me. Also how can I add time and date `02:30pm 10 01, 2021` to data? and that should display in when mouseHover on the graph(edges).

Right now I have tried sample graph with static data like

```
const data = [
 {
  name: 'Page A',
  uv: 4000,
  pv: 2400,
  amt: 2400,
 },
 {
  name: 'Page B',
  uv: 3000,
  pv: 1398,
  amt: 2210,
 },
 {
  name: 'Page C',
  uv: 2000,
  pv: 9800,
  amt: 2290,
 },
]
return(
  <LineChart
      width={900}
      height={250}
      data={data}
      margin={{
        top: 35,
        right: 30,
        left: 20,
        bottom: 5,
      }}
    >
      <Tooltip />
      <Legend />
      <Line type="monotone" dataKey="uv" stroke="#4ec6f4" activeDot={{ r: 8 }} />
   </LineChart>
 )
```

Also how to add custom content for `Tooltip`?

Answer (score 1):

For your question regarding Tooltip,
<Tooltip formatter={(n) => `${n} months`}/>

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, Recharts does not provide a way to filter your data. I would recommend writing a function that filters your data before you pass it to the chart. You can actually just add a date property to all of your data items. I would do some research to find a date string format that suits your needs and is understood by the Javascript Date class.

browse here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Then you can work with your dates as Date objectsand perform logic on them: [How to check if one DateTime is later than another in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20322507/how-to-check-if-one-datetime-is-later-than-another-in-javascript)